# XNA invader shooting in space invaders

Tags: c#, xna

so I was told to write a code and then post my problem. So I did.
this is the invader shooting code:

```
 Texture2D Background;
    Texture2D invader;
    Texture2D invaderBullet;
    Rectangle rectInvaderBullet;
    Rectangle[,] rectInvader;
    bool[,] isInvaderAlive;
    const int rows = 5;
    const int cols = 10;
    bool invaderBulletVisible = false;
    const int bulletSpeed = 5;
    int invaderSpeed = 2;
    int invadersAliveCounter;
```

Update:

```
`//invader shooting thinking begin
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            {
                int check = rnd.Next(0, 1000);
                if (check < 800 && invaderBulletVisible == false)
                {
                    invaderBulletVisible = true;
                    rectInvaderBullet.X = rectInvader[r, c].X + (rectInvader[r, c].Width / 2) - (rectInvaderBullet.Width / 2);
                    rectInvaderBullet.Y = rectInvader[r, c].Y - rectInvaderBullet.Height + 35;
                }
                if (invaderBulletVisible)
                    rectInvaderBullet.Y = rectInvaderBullet.Y + bulletSpeed;                    
            }
        //invader shooting thinking end`
```

and this is the draw code:

```
if (invaderBulletVisible)
            spriteBatch.Draw(invaderBullet, rectInvaderBullet, Color.White);
```

Now of course something is wrong. First off I'm an amatuer and I haven't even finished school but I'm trying my best. Secondly, the bullet isn't even appearing. The bullet isn't even appearing. So basically I want to understand why. And also, how do I make it so that only an invader with no one infront of it can shoot?
Thank you so much in advance!!!

Comment: Set some breakpoints and see what code is/isn't being run.   Does `invaderBulletVisible` ever get set to true?

Comment: Yes it is. I put check on 800 just to see if it enters and if anything is alright and it ran perfectly.
Well except for the drawing. That's why I'm so confused. I mean, it looks right doesn't it?